# Background color fade effect as i scroll through images in UIScrollView (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicolor

I'm have a number of images in a UIScrollView, in which I have calculated the average color for the images, but I want the background color (average color) to fade from one color to the next as I scroll through the images. Here's what I want (notice the background color effect as I scroll through the images on ebay):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3fFlkF0j7y9VDVycTg3aklCbDg/view

Source file so far here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uw874rb8r9ytzrg/TestApp.zip?dl=0

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  func fade(fromRed: CGFloat,
              fromGreen: CGFloat,
              fromBlue: CGFloat,
              fromAlpha: CGFloat,
              toRed: CGFloat,
              toGreen: CGFloat,
              toBlue: CGFloat,
              toAlpha: CGFloat,
              withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor {

    let red: CGFloat = (toRed - fromRed) * percentage + fromRed
    let green: CGFloat = (toGreen - fromGreen) * percentage + fromGreen
    let blue: CGFloat = (toBlue - fromBlue) * percentage + fromBlue
    let alpha: CGFloat = (toAlpha - fromAlpha) * percentage + fromAlpha

    // return the fade colour
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and add some explanation to it. That would help a lot